# Edit current stream (Post)

Tags: getstream-io

I have a query. How we can edit the current stream and how we can ,make sure that same user is editing the stream . for e.g. If I created a post and now I want to edit that post. Is it possible? and how to make sure that only I can edit this post

Comment: what language / framework are you using in your project?

Comment: I am using PHP/Laravel

Answer (score 0):

If you use Laravel and the [stream-laravel](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-laravel) integration this comes out of the box, the only thing you need to do is follow the instructions from the Readme.

In your case you probably want to have a Post model that uses the ActivityTrait trait. After that you only need to add the correct ACL for objects within Laravel (eg. only allow the author of a post to edit that post)